# Eclipse kepler full screen mode pulgin?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a plugin to full-creen mode in the Eclipse kepler? I mean I would like to work without command menu, tabs etc. Just only code window increased to full-screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/

Answer (score 0):

There aee few option available for Eclipse full screen feature

1. [http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/) (As @ConMan answered)
   Download jar and put in `plugin folder` of eclipse
2. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fullscreen-mode [Plugin on marketplace]
   Install from `Marketplace` or in eclipse `Help -> Install New Software`

All are working fine on 3.4+ version of eclipse

For OSX Lion,

1. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/full-screen-enabler-eclipse-3637-osx-lion [Plugin on marketplace]

This plugin works for Eclipse 3.6/3.7(Not verified by me)